# Trying to convert Sed command to Python re.sub

Tags: python, regex, sed

I am trying to convert the below Sed command to python re.sub. The Sed command is basically extracting the access_token value from the json string.

```
finalString=$(echo $initialString |  sed -e 's/^.*"access_token":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/')
```

My Python code, I was stuck in replacing the \1 part. I have to replace the whole string with the value

```
access_token = re.sub('^.*"access_token":"\([^"]*\)".*$',r'\1',initialString)
print access_token
```

My working echo statement is as follows, When I run this I am getting the access_token value. For Ex: If `initialString ='{"access_token":"xyz"}'` output will be `xyz`.

```
echo initialString | sed -e 's/^.*"access_token":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

Comment: What is `initialString`? What is happening, or not happening, that makes you ask this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should make it a rule to always use raw-strings as regular expressions in Python. (In specific, it doesn't matter here. But it's a good rule of thumb.)

Try this:

```
access_token = re.sub(r'^.*"access_token":"([^"]*)".*$', r'\1', initialString)
```

Comment: Here is the working echo function that I have
`echo inputString | sed -e 's/^.*"access_token":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'`

Comment: It worked. My bad I passed the wrong inpuString. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the assumption that your `intialString` is something along the lines of: `"other":"json","access_token":"(1234)","more":"json"`

```
access_token = re.sub(r'^.*"access_token":"\(([^\)]*)\)".*$',r'\1',initialString)
```

The problem I noticed was that you were never actually capturing any characters to reference with \1.